# Why do I keep getting 404's when using @AutoConfigureMockMvc in SpringBoot test?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, mockmvc, springrunner

I'm trying to write an integration test using springrunner. I'm running it as a springboottest and using autoconfiguremockmvc. However, i keep getting 404s. It seems my controllers/endpoints aren't being loaded by the autoconfiguremockmvc. Does anyone know a solution of how to wire this up so that it will pick up my controllers?

I did add a basic controller into my test class and i was able to hit it successfully but I have been unable so far to hit the actual controller I want to use in my integration test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URL).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                        .content(json);

        final ResponseEntity<String> response =
                new ResponseEntity<>("works", HttpStatus.OK);

        final ResultActions result = this.mockMvc.perform(request).andDo(print());

        result.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
    }
}

@TestConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

}
```

Comment: `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` is, as the name implies, only for configuring `MockMvc` it doesn't detect anything else. Your problem is that you are using a seperate configuration for your test. You should be using just an `@SpringBootTest` annotation and let it detect/load your full application and not a test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment =
>   SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

and **RestAssured** library in combination to test any endpoint/api like below

```
// include dependency in pom
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

</dependency>

//Test Class

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntTest{

//inject test local port
@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    //assign port for reset assured
    RestAssured.port = port;
}
@Test
public void test() {

    given()
            .get("/api")
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body("name", is("test"));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your use case, controller and tests?